# Ctesibius discovery of compressed air

Tags: biographical-details

I want to know where has he placed the tube and how he adjust the height ?
Please refer the link below marked in violet http://lnr.li/m19fP 
Please explain using simple diagram for better understanding

Comment: Please anybody give the answer

Comment: Note that the article is not about a compressed air test system but about a system where he noticed air compressing.

Comment: Answer anybody with proper diagram

Answer (score 1):

I think the setup is too trivial for most history pages to bother with, but there is a picture in the book "Young Explorers’ Guide : The Search for Ingenious Treasures" . Unfortunately, that picture does not display in the Google Books search.

This is a simple case of a lever arm: the mirror remains at a fixed distance from the pivot, while the lead weight can move.  According to other descriptions, the mirror is positioned by means of a pulley& rope which presumably is tied down.  The movement of the lead weight is almost irrelevant other than to provide stability for the entire lever arm at any mirror height.

Comment: Please provide a diagram which might give me a clear idea

Comment: Please explain .....................